# Using failover connection with NEST is throwing strange exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to setup 2 elasticsearch nodes and for testing they are set up on local machine. With this settings.

```
cluster.name: TestCluster
node.name: "Node1"
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200

cluster.name: CMTCluster
node.name: "Node2"
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9201
```

When using normal connection everything works fine when pointing to either node.

```
var node1 = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node1, "document");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var result = client.Search<Customer>(s => s
            .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Query("Abse").OnField(p => p.FullName))));
```

When using client with static connection pool everything breaks apart.

```
var node1 = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var node2 = new Uri("http://localhost:9201");

var connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(new[] { node1, node2 });

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, "cmt-zurich-steva");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var result = client.Search<Customer>(s => s
            .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Query("Abse").OnField(p => p.FullName))));
```

Exception is:

```
Failed after retrying 1 times: 'POST document/customer/_search'. 
InnerException: PingException, InnerMessage: Pinging http://localhost:9201/ caused an exception, InnerStackTrace:    at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.ITransportDelegator.Ping(ITransportRequestState requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\Transport.cs:line 108
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.SelectNextNode[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 45
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 117
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 149
InnerException: PingException, InnerMessage: Pinging http://localhost:9200/ caused an exception, InnerStackTrace:    at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.ITransportDelegator.Ping(ITransportRequestState requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\Transport.cs:line 108
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.SelectNextNode[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 45
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 117
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 149
```

Strangest thing is that after the exception is trowed if I let the program continue it will give me the correct results.
I am missing something but have no idea what.

Comment: It's possible that the ping timeout is set to low for your network.    The default is 200ms, can you try increasing it via: `settings.PingTimeout()` and see if that does it?

Comment: @Greg Marzouka That was it. I already tried with half a second but that was too low also apparently. Increased to second and it works now. Thanks you.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. The problem was not in the ping. When I try it on my machine with urls http://localhost:... it does not work whatever PingTimeout I set. When I try elasticsearch instances on test server with urls like http://192.168.4.10:... everything works fine.

Comment: have the same problem, any updates on it how to make it work locally?

Comment: You can't use localhost for some reason. But you when I used my computers name in our internal network as hostname in config and as url everything worked fine.